# Save Action on webforms for marketers throws exception

Tags: submit, sitecore, nullreferenceexception, web-forms-for-marketers

I am using the latest version of Sitecore - 7.2 (rev. 140228) and the latest version of WFFM - 2.4 rev. 140923. So the problem is whenever I try to submit a form no matter what kind of save action I have, Sitecore throws exception:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Controllers.ModelBinders.FormModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +571
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +457
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +152
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +641
```

Some additional information. The latest version of WFFM supports MVC so in this scenario I use cshtml layout. This is the blog post where is described how to use MVC - [THIS](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/06/Sitecore-MVC-Playground-Part-1-Enable-MVC.aspx) Despite it is for previous versions of SC it doesn't matter and the solution is applicable for the latest version.

Comment: Are you using custom form model ?

Comment: I tried with my own custom made form and also with the predefined forms in /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Sample forms/... The result is the same

Comment: Are you sure that the MVC is working as expected ? Also have you checked this article and make sure everything you are trying to do is compatible with MVC ? http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/24/web%20forms%20for%20marketers%20v2_4%20reference-a4.pdf

Comment: Yes. For example in my simple custom form I am using only on field of type "Single-Line Text" which has "MVC Type"- "Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.Fields.SingleLineTextField,Sitecore.Forms.Mvc". So I think I am using it correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think I have a solution for this.

I reverse engineered and debugged using a version of the controller and model binder I created after reflecting on the `Sitecore.Forms.MVC` classes using `ILSpy`.

Apparently the `null` reference is occuring when it hits this:

```
if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestType == "POST" && formId != item.ID)
```

`item` is `null`. `item` is set in the line before:

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.PageContext.Database.GetItem(RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering.DataSource);
```

The data source property is empty on the rendering. If you check your presentation details, you'll see that's because there is another field that is used to specify your form ID. Apparently this looks like a `Sitecore` bug. But an easy workaround is to set the form data source in both the form ID and the Data source property of the rendering.